# How are addresses ordered in Tezos?

Tags: address, order

Datatypes that can be made into sets must have a defined order. And since `set(address)` is a valid data type, what is the ordering of addresses?

If you make an instance of type  `set(address)`, how are the addresses ordered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `address` data type is ordered lexicographically, so that `tz2...` comes before `tz3...` and `tz2a...` comes before `tz2b...` etc. But originated accounts, addresses that start with `KT1`, come after any implicit accounts, those that start with `tz`. So all addresses starting with `KT1` are ordered lexicographically but they come after all `tz` addresses.

This ordering is described [here](https://michelson.nomadic-labs.com/#instr-COMPARE).